# XSLT select multiply value of same field name in the same node and display

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML code and I try to display by using XSLT. How to select the fieldname and return all value in a table. I tried but it won't work, just only return first record ('username' and 'user'). Please help, many thanks.

XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xml_list_new.xsl"?>
<root>
   <record>
     <fieldname>username</fieldname>
        <value>user</value>
     <fieldname>ipaddress</fieldname>
        <value>127.0.0.1</value>
     <fieldname>lastaction</fieldname>
        <value>2011-06-13 00:53:05</value>
     <fieldname>sessionid</fieldname>
        <value>h0atrutpu5vgrvuf3ipledfbvl1</value>
    </record>
    <record>
     <fieldname>username</fieldname>
        <value>admin</value>
     <fieldname>ipaddress</fieldname>
        <value>127.0.0.1</value>
     <fieldname>lastaction</fieldname>
        <value>2011-06-12 00:43:53</value>
     <fieldname>sessionid</fieldname>
        <value>nnbdofsdq4sd7e3def3hnid9</value>
    </record>
    <record>
     <fieldname>username</fieldname>
         <value>ccm</value>
     <fieldname>ipaddress</fieldname>
        <value>127.0.0.1</value>
     <fieldname>lastaction</fieldname>
        <value>2011-06-10 00:30:22</value>
     <fieldname>sessionid</fieldname>
        <value>di34bndffgrt48cmkl08d8e4</value>
    </record>
 </root>
```

XSLT code

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method='html'/>
<xsl:param name="title">XML List</xsl:param>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title><xsl:value-of select="$title"/></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        <![CDATA[

          caption { font-weight: bold; }
          th {
          background: #2C3033;
          color: #fff;
          font-family: arial;
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: 12px;
          }
          tr {
            font-family: arial;
            color: #000;
            font-size: 12px;
            background: #E0E0E0;
          }

        ]]>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center" style="width: 800px; margin: 0 auto">
    <table border="0" style="width: 800px">
        <caption><xsl:value-of select="$title"/></caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <xsl:for-each select="root/record">
                <th >
                <xsl:value-of select="fieldname"/>
                </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <xsl:for-each select="root/record">
        <tr>
            <td ><xsl:value-of select="value"/></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this template. I've tried to follow your template as much as possible. I've added just a single template (and cleaned up the output for readability).

[XSTL 1.0]

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="root/record[1]/fieldname">
                        <th>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </th>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:for-each select="root/record">
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="value"/>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>    
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="value">
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces the following table:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>username</th>
         <th>ipaddress</th>
         <th>lastaction</th>
         <th>sessionid</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>user</td>
         <td>127.0.0.1</td>
         <td>2011-06-13 00:53:05</td>
         <td>h0atrutpu5vgrvuf3ipledfbvl1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>admin</td>
         <td>127.0.0.1</td>
         <td>2011-06-12 00:43:53</td>
         <td>nnbdofsdq4sd7e3def3hnid9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>ccm</td>
         <td>127.0.0.1</td>
         <td>2011-06-10 00:30:22</td>
         <td>di34bndffgrt48cmkl08d8e4</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, the code does work but I got another problem, which it display without line break and the head of the table duplicated by the number of set of record in XML. How to fix this problem, thanks.

Comment: output that I want is a normal table with one set of head like this.
`<table>
 <tr>
    <th>username</th>
    <th>ipaddress</th>
    <th>lastaction</th>
    <th>sessionid</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>user</td>
   <td>127.0.0.1</td>
   <td>2011-06-13 00:53:05</td>
   <td>h0atrutpu5vgrvuf3ipledfbvl1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>admin</td>
   <td>127.0.0.1</td>
   <td>2011-06-12 00:43:53</td>
   <td>nnbdofsdq4sd7e3def3hnid9</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>ccm</td>
   <td>127.0.0.1</td>
   <td>2011-06-10 00:30:22</td>
   <td>di34bndffgrt48cmkl08d8e4</td>
 </tr>
 </table>`

Comment: You should be able to edit your original question and remove the comments above.